# Ways to deal with files common to various git/svn projects?

Tags: git, svn, project-management

I have many software projects (C, scripts, etc) under git or svn, from small to fairly large. Many of those share a few common files. What are the best ways to deal with those single or pairs (.h/.c) of files ?

Ideally I'd like those to be in separate git repositories, with some kind of automatic pull/commit/push when they are modified in one of the projects. I think there are some ways to do this in git, but are there under svn as well ?

Currently I have them in separate repositories and try to keep everything on the same filesystem and use hardlinks for those files when used in the main project directories. But it's easy to make mistakes, loose the links, etc... Suggestions ?

Comment: You shouldn't have "files" that are shared; all files within a Git project should be contained within the same folder (with `.git`). You may have shared *APIs* that you need to call, which should be in an independent repo and called though an HTTP request. Alternatively you could bundle the common files and reference them as a Nuget Package or similar.

Comment: They are mostly C projects, no HTTP here. Sure, I could make libs/dlls/so, keep the source in one place and just copy the binaries, but it complicate things. That's the traditional solution of before git/svn.

Answer (score 0):

For the `git` version I would bet on the [submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). It requires to get some new habits (updating your submodules and co.) but can be very powerful.

I do not know such equivalent for SVN. If you want a cross-VCS solution, maybe you have to write a simple script which check the current VCS (git or svn) and run the appropriate commands (submodules for git, full clone for svn).

Comment: I tried submodules and it seems to do what I want for git. But something escapes me. I a colleague does a git pull on the main project, he doesn't get the submodule.

Comment: @dargaud Yes, this is some of the new habits to have. If new submodules have been added you have to init them after your pull: `git pull; git submodules init`. If submodules have been updated, you have to update them `git pull ; git submodules update`. I find [this](https://gist.github.com/gitaarik/8735255#getting-the-submodules-code) clear and simple, a good start to play with submodules.